# MVC : File.exists return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, iis, system.io.file

I have a MVC method like this :

```
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(string filePath){
   //Other stuff
   if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
   {
       FileLogger.Debug($"DownloadDocument : {filePath} NotFound");
   }
   //Other stuff
}
```

filePath looks like => `\\ServerB\Documents\General\Administration\Doc1.pdf`

In local I have a IISExpress (I know that's not great but no choice...) and a data server (Server B). File is on server B.
It works really good, I can retrieve my file.

When publishing, I have a IIS on Server A and a the same data Server (Server B). FilePath is still on server B. 
In this case, I can't retrieve my file because this line returns False :

```
System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)
```

Searching a solution, I see ServerMapPath but it's not helping because filePath is on Server B, not Server A.

When I connect myself to the server A, if in the file explorer I put the link `\\ServerB\Documents\General\Administration\Doc1.pdf`, file is retrieved correctly.

Maybe it's a security problem but don't know where to search...

Thank you for your help

Comment: It might be that the IIS user has no access to the given path.

Comment: you mean you want to access a file from Server B with the deployed Application on Server A?

Comment: IISExpress runs under *your* credentials, and *you* have access to ServerB. IIS runs under some service account, which apparently does *not* have access.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an access rights issue. The folder does exist, but .NET can't determine that because the IIS user doesn't have access to the network share.

You can check this by running the IIS application pool as an network user, for example your own account. **Don't do this in production scenarios!** Create a separate domain account for the IIS user.

Comment: I agree with you . " Don't do this in production scenarios! Create a separate domain account for the IIS user."

Answer (score 2):

Try to create an Application Pool that can access the file from Server B.

```
Right-Click Application Pool > Advanced Settings
```

[image]

Go to Process Model Section > Identity > Click ApplicationPoolIdentity

From Built-in account. Select > Custom account: > Cick Set >

Set Credentials will popup. 
    [image]

Set your credentials and assign the Application Pool to your application on Server A.

Make sure the User Credential has access to Server B file.

Hope this will help.